# Which keyboard mappings are still available?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm recording some macro like: collapsing all outlining, locating opened file in solution explorer, opening the pending changes pane... But I'm having difficulty in choosing the keyboard mapping for my macros. It seems like any mapping I choose are reserved by Visual Studio IDE default setting.

What mappings are you using?

[Edit]
I found the below: Ctrl + ' Ctrl + ` You may have others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Ctrl-Shift 3, Ctrl-Shift 4 etc. You can get a good stretch running there. Also, just because a key is bound by default doesn't mean you can't use it. I probably wouldn't re-use Ctrl+S but if you never use Ctrl+W for whatever it's bound to, go ahead and bind it to your macro. They're your settings. It's your copy of the program.

Comment: I'm not fond of changing the default hotkey since that will create a new habit differs you way from what MS default thinks.